# Switch case is not working with Enum in Java

Tags: java

When I tried switch statement with Enum, I don't understand what is happening.

The following code is giving error as

> An enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an
> enumeration constant

```
   Browser browser = Browser.IE;
   case Browser.IE:     
       System.out.println("Switch --Running in IE");
       break;
```

However, when I use like below, it's working fine.

```
   case IE:
       System.out.println("Switch --Running in IE");
       break;
```

What is the difference between both, why `Browser.IE` is not working?
In case of if statement, `if (browser==Browser.IE)`, it's accepting `Browser.IE`.
I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: You've already found the solution. Switches on enums have a special rule which says that you use the unqualified name. So use that.

Comment: As to why, perhaps the feeling is that if you are qualifying them it's less obvious that they must all be from the same enum. It's certainly more readable anyway.

Comment: Hint: `Browser.IE` is a qualified name (the name of the `enum` itself is written) and `IE` is the unqualified one.